# Cannot convert the value of parameter 'Date' to the type 'System.DateTime'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, radgrid

I use `EntityDataSource` , i get an error conversion after i format my date

like that :`DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"`

```
[EntityDataSourceValidationException: Error while setting property 'fromDate': 'Cannot convert the value of parameter 'fromDate' to the type 'System.DateTime'.'.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource.EntityDataSourceView.ConvertProperties(IDictionary values, PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptors, ParameterCollection referenceParameters, Dictionary`2 convertedValues) +737
   Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteDelete(IDictionary keys, IDictionary oldValues) +383
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Delete(IDictionary keys, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +84
   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformDelete(GridEditableItem editedItem, Boolean suppressRebind) +228
   Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs.ExecuteCommand(Object source) +2417
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
```

---

**My aspx:**

```
 <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn HeaderText="تاريخ البداية" UniqueName="fromDate" SortExpression="fromDate" DataField="fromDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
```

---

> Note : `fromDate` of type `Date` in sqlserver db

Comment: `DataField="fromDate"` shouldn't be `DataField=fromDate`?

Comment: @SonerGönül: Could u explain what do you mean ? `DataField` is a property of grid column

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fromDate" DataType="System.DateTime" HeaderText="تاريخ البداية"     
  UniqueName="fromDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false"/>
```

Comment: the insertion is okay but when i try to delete the row  i get the same error